# reconstruct time series from SSA

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd

let us consider following code

```
clear all;
  B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
  n=length(B);
  L =input('Give the size of the interval: ' );% Number of columns in the Data matrix
   m=n-L+1;%number of rows in the Data matrix
 X = zeros(m,L);
  for i=1:m
        X(i,:)=B(i:i+L-1);
  end;
   S=X*X'; 
    [U,autoval]=eig(S);
    [d,i]=sort(-diag(autoval));  
   d=-d;
   U=U(:,i);sev=sum(d); 
    plot((d./sev)*100),hold on,plot((d./sev)*100,'rx');
    title('Singular Spectrum');xlabel('Eigenvalue Number');ylabel('Eigenvalue (% Norm of trajectory matrix retained)')
   V=(X')*U; 
   rc=U*V';
% Step 3: Grouping
   I=input('Choose the agrupation of components to reconstruct the series in the form I=[i1,i2:ik,...,iL]  ')
   Vt=V';
   rca=U(:,I)*Vt(I,:);
% Step 4: Reconstruction

   y=zeros(n,1);  
   Lp=min(L,m);
   Kp=max(L,m);

   for k=0:Lp-2
     for m1=1:k+1;
      y(k+1)=y(k+1)+(1/(k+1))*rca(m1,k-m1+2);
     end
   end

   for k=Lp-1:Kp-1
     for m1=1:Lp;
      y(k+1)=y(k+1)+(1/(Lp))*rca(m1,k-m1+2);
     end
   end

   for k=Kp:n
      for m1=k-Kp+2:n-Kp+1;
       y(k+1)=y(k+1)+(1/(n-k))*rca(m1,k-m1+2);
     end
   end

   figure;subplot(2,1,1);hold on;xlabel('Data poit');ylabel('Original and reconstructed series')
   plot(x1);grid on;plot(y,'r')
   r=x1-y;
   subplot(2,1,2);plot(r,'g');xlabel('Data poit');ylabel('Residual series');grid on
   vr=(sum(d(I))/sev)*100;
```

The fragment of code was used from this site:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8115-singular-spectrum-analysis-smoother/content/ssa.m

When I am running this code `averaging`

```
Give the size of the interval: 15
Choose the agrupation of components to reconstruct the series in the form I=[i1,i2:ik,...,iL]  4

I =

     4

Attempted to access rca(1,16); index out of bounds because size(rca)=[280,15].

Error in averaging (line 37)
      y(k+1)=y(k+1)+(1/(Lp))*rca(m1,k-m1+2);
```

What is problem in my code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you are trying to access the 16th column of `rca` and `rca` only has 15 columns.

Running your code in Octave, I get the following values:

```
>> I
I =  4
>> Kp
Kp =  280
>> Lp
Lp =  15
>> n
n =  294
>> m
m =  280
```

The code errors when `k=15` and `m1=1`, which gives `k-m1+2 = 16`, hence the error message.

**EDIT**

Rather than modify the function, why not simply call it with your data?

```
clear all;
B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
L =input('Give the size of the interval: ' );% Number of columns in the Data matrix
[y,r,vr]=ssa(B,L);
```

Comment: how to fix it?because  it is taken from the  official site,it should work right

Comment: I don't know... I've explained to you why you were getting the error message. It's up to you or the person who wrote this to fix it. Although it's "taken from the official website", it is still something written by a user, like you and me, not by a professional software developer at MathWorks. The File Exchange and MATLAB Central are a user community (the emphasis being on user).

Comment: I notice that the original code has some dimension checking in the first bit (`Step1 : Build trayectory matrix`), which you are not doing. I suspect the problem comes from here. Your `L` is not checked as the original code does in `if L>N/2;L=N-L;`

Comment: yes but  this checking code does not produce correct  data matrix

Comment: by the way i have  added this line,no   result

Comment: so there is no solution of this problem?

Comment: i will explain,this code  will not return same  data matrix,i meant  problem is in data matrix  createion

Comment: Then, I'm sorry but you need to fix how you are creating your matrix to make sure it is the correct size as per the original file on MATLAB Central. failing that, you can try to contact the original author.

Comment: could we discuss in chat?

Comment: i have contacted author,i hope he will help me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this working GNU Octave compatible Basic SSA implementation: [ssa-octave.m](https://gist.github.com/werediver/10886388). This is an adaptation of my Scilab code which works fine for me. Pay attention to the comments inside, they may contain some important notes.

If you're interested I can also provide an M-SSA (multivariate) implementation. It's pretty close to Basic SSA and differs only in time delay embedding and diagonal averaging phases.

I want to say that SSA looks to me like (and I believe it is) [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) applied to time delay embedding of a time series.