# What is agrupation, in the context of Singular Spectrum Analysis?

Tags: matlab, matrix

A popular program for Singular Spectrum Analysis is on [reconstruct time series from SSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106669/reconstruct-time-series-from-ssa).

There are the lines, which ask the user to input a matrix.

```
% Step 3: Grouping    I=input('Choose the agrupation of components to
reconstruct the series in the form I=[i1,i2:ik,...,iL]  ')
```

What is the user supposed to enter here?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what agrupation means!? However, the function is asking you to select which of the Principal Components that will NOT be used to reconstruct the series.

For example if using SSA to detrend a time series: if only the first PC contains a significant trend then the detrended time series would be reconstructed using all the PCs except PC1 (i.e. the addition of PCs 2:M, with M being the total number of dimensions).

Basically, it is asking you which of the PCs you wish to subtract from the original series in order to detrend it.

For a better explanation, I suggest you read the original paper of [Vautard et al. (1992)](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=singular-spectrum%20analysis:%20a%20toolkit%20for%20short,%20noisy%20chaotic%20signals.&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=f0VCVYm3HsztaNbTgIgO&ved=0CB8QgQMwAA). The topic of your question is discussed on page 111.

I hope that helps,

Mike